# How can I plot the physical location of devices in a way that will allow me to find all devices nearby to a given device?

Tags: dictionary, location, plot

Here's an example layout:

```
    A
B       C

D
    G    F
E
            H
K       I
    J
```

Each letter represents a physical device. In this example, you can see that `A` is nearby to both `B` and `C`. `B` is nearby to both `A`, `D` and possibly `C`.

I was thinking of putting each device into a database and pairing all possibly relationships. For example:

```
device | siblings
-------+---------
A      | B,C
-------+---------
B      | A,D,C
-------+---------
D      | B,G,E
```

This way, when I need to find the devices nearby to `D` I can do:

```
SELECT siblings FROM devices WHERE device = 'D';

siblings = siblings.split(',')

for sibling in siblings:
    # do something with each sibling device
```

I was wondering if there was a better way. Given that there could be large number of devices, I feel this method could get messy and, likely, buggy (human error of keeping track of the command separated list of siblings).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the Wikipedia article for [Nearest-Neighbour Search](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) for more ideas, but the best answer probably depends on the number of devices you're going to be working with.

[KD-Trees](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Kd_tree) and [R-Trees](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/R-tree) will give you good performance even on large numbers of devices, but they'll require a good bit of programming / debugging (if you have to do them yourself, at least - they're reasonably well-known data structures, so you might be able to find a library somewhere).

If you've only got a small number of devices ("small" depends on all sorts of things, really), it might be faster to skip the complexity of a special data structure and just do a linear search through all your devices.  And if you're only performing queries like this occasionally, a slow linear search might still be worth having clean, straightforward code.

And finally:  All the above options assume that all devices are "connected" to one another.  If only some devices are connected to each other, try using an [Adjacency List](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Adjacency_list) to store those connections, and keep it sorted by distance - this should be faster than any of the above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll look into these and see if I can find one to suit my needs. Cheers.